# Why is .getMonth() returning 11 for January?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes a date and a date format and converts it. This specific part of the function converts dates to a nice month format `Month abbreviation Year`. However, `getMonth()` on January 1st is returning 11. Why?

Debugging code:

```
console.log(d)
console.log(d.getMonth())
console.log(d.getMonth() + 1)
console.log(months[d.getMonth() + 1])
```

Output:

```
2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
11
12
undefined
```

**Edit**

See @deceze's comment below. The issue was that the timezone is in UTC and my current timezone was changing the date to december so `getMonth()` was getting 11.

Comment: The actual date is in a different time zone where it’s still December, but is being printed as string in UTC…?

Comment: How do you init you d date object?

Comment: I am getting 0 in my system

Comment: Really, like @maximelian1986 said, we need to know what `d` is. We're assuming it is a `Date` but it could be something else. Even if it is, its possible someone messed with it. `Date.prototype.getMonth = function(){return 11;};`

Comment: d is created with a `new Date()` call but you're right. It's likely getting modified slightly to not be a date.

Comment: @deceze feel free to right an answer and I can mark it as correct. The timezone was causing the date to be december which returned 11. My workaround for all the other months was to add 1 but that doesn't work for January.

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools `Date()` reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) you are using a date in iso format, so you have to call `new Date("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")` before playing with it

```js
d = new Date("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
console.log(d);
console.log(d.getMonth());
console.log(d.getMonth() + 1);
```